# vertical-align="middle" for td is not working if we use <!doctype ...>

Tags: html, xhtml

I am trying to middle align an element, But I have bumped into this problem. I am using this tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
      <table style="width:100%; height: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td vertical-align="middle">
                        <div id="progressContainer" style="text-align:center;">
                            Some string here                                                    
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>       
            </table>  
  </body>
</html>
```

If I remove this: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`, its middle aligned properly.

This behavior is reproducible in FF and chrome.

Question:

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Do not use `<td vertical-align="middle">`. See http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in Quirks mode, browsers make deliberate errors.

Since the height of the `body` element is `auto` (the default), the `height: 100%` on the `table` element becomes `auto`.

(Percentage heights are converted to `auto` if the parent element has `height: auto`)

Comment: I gave <body height="100%">, did not have an effect on the output.

Comment: … the HTML element still has `height: auto` so the body get that too!

Comment: But I dont want to specify height in harcoded pixels which could introduce UI bugs. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 6):

The attribute is `valign="middle"` or `style="vertical-align: middle"`. There is no attribute `vertical-align`.

See [11.3.2 Horizontal and vertical alignment](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.2)

Comment: I tried with <td style="vertical-align: middle">, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try adding borders to the `table` (and perhaps the `td`) to see that the table actually has a height. Are you using any devtools, e.g. Firebug?

Comment: Yes I am using firebug, let me check that.

Comment: Firebug let's you see the implicit and explicit styles associated with any DOM object. Very useful for debugging strange or unexpected behaviour.

Comment: It seems default height is being applied in quirks mode. height: 100% is not taken into account, however width: 100% is applied.

Comment: As David says, you have to apply `height: 100%` to `html`, `body` and `table` for it to work. See the source of my example.